# Database becoming unresponsive after time (4 to 24 hours)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

Since a couple of days my mariadb database randomly becomes unresponsive after random intervals (which have been between 4 and 20 hours).

The database comes back to life when rebooting the ct.
And after some time these queries start to fail with `MySqlException (0x80004005): The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed`. 
I have also noticed that sometimes restarting the mariadb-service also gets stuck.

Below is all information I have on the issue:

### System Info

Ubuntu: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Mariadb: 10.6.7
Proxmox: 7.2-3

### Fixing attemps

- Fresh install (vm) importing old data (only copying the database `fivem`) using mysqldump
- `mysqlcheck --all-databases --auto-repair` (while mysql is working. When it is in the unresponsive state, there's no output.

### Proxmox

This is a screenshot of all information on the proxmox CT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fan2O.png

### Data and structure

It happens in a database called fivem which has multiple tables. Notably only the bigger ones are stuck (meaning that `select * from TABLE_NAME` will not finish for a long time).

Phpmyadmin table (content): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A0P0.png 
Phpmyadmin table (size and "is hung"): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnp5P.png

### MariaDB Config

I have done these modification to the default config:

```
skip-name-resolve
max_allowed_packet      = 1G
max_connections         = 100000
table_cache             = 640
thread_handling         = pool-of-threads
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48103633715
```

### INNODB

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` was also unresponsive.

### Processlist

Shows multiple queries on mostly the states `commit` and `sending data` (some `commits`).

Hastebin-Link to full processlist: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/sapajapohi.sql

### Syslog

Shows a lot of `Got an error reading communication packets` and `(This connection closed normally without authentication`.
Note that these happen while mysql is operational too.

Some examples: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/rewozofana.yaml

### Mariadb service

Output while starting: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/uracoqutab.yaml

Restarting the mariadb service also did not work. The last warning it shows are: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/usewerugut.less

### Conclusion

If anyone has ideas of what the issue might be **or just ideas on how to further debug this** I would really appreciate it.

### Edit / Updates

- max_connections has been lowered to 250 but will need to be increased
- innodb_buffer has also been lowered
- It has become apparent that shortly after (or right before) the unresponsivness a lot of Disk IO is observed (20x the usual amount)
- mysql status shows some warnings the quickly increase in size (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2hDM.png). I am not sure if these could be a cause and how to fix them for now
- I noticed that restarting the service (mariadb) occasionally got it stuck at `Waiting to flush the buffer pool` with the last messages being

```
May 19 08:11:06 database systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.6.7 database server...
May 19 08:11:06 database mariadbd[659]: 2022-05-19  8:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
May 19 08:11:06 database mariadbd[659]: 2022-05-19  8:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
May 19 08:11:06 database mariadbd[659]: 2022-05-19  8:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 19 08:11:06 database mariadbd[659]: 2022-05-19  8:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220519  8:11:06
```

Comment: Do you expect 100K concurrent connections? If so, you should do something about it. If you don't, then why did you set `max_connections         = 100000`?

Comment: @mustaccio That is a fair point. I do not expect 100000 connections. I had some problems where the default of 100 was not enough so I changed it to the maximum.
Could this be a possible cause for the problems?

Comment: Update on @mustaccio 's suggestion. I tried it with a limit of 250 and sadly the database just became unresponsive again.

Comment: My best guess is that it is somehow running out of space. Since only the bigger tables are affected. However I don't know what space it could be since innodb_buffer_pool_size is set high enough to my understanding.

Comment: How much RAM do you actually have? Where have you set your default configuration? The startup shows that its still reading 128M for the innodb buffer pool from the configuration file rather than you 48G setting (which looking at your table sizes is wastefully large).

Comment: @danblack I have 64 Gigs of ddr4 ecc available. I went with the default recommendation of 80% for the buffer_pool_size. But after posting the question I changed it to 8G which seems to have taken effect. (Sql shows an innodb_buffer_pool_size of "8589934592").

Comment: Take a look at `show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool%'`. While 80% is a frequent rule, if your RAM is bigger than your active dataset it does create a little bit of waste. So it looks like its going unresponsive after an IO spike (assuming innodb flushing but it could be anything).

Comment: @danblack The IO spike also had me wondering. I have now decreased the buffer_pool to 256M. I also noticed that "Handler read rnd next" is growing very fast: https://i.imgur.com/Vc60Ptt.png (this is a screenshot after 5 minutes uptime).
I will see how this develops during uptime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a known issue on proxmox+mariadb

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/snapshot-backup-not-working-guest-agent-fs-freeze-gets-timeout.99887/page-2

Answer (score 1):

I have probably found the cause and it's a weird edge case.

I have the cts (from proxmox) running on lvm instead of lvm-thin. And had a backup job using snapshot for the database every 4 hours. My guess is that since snapshot was unavailable it froze the ct for the backup and somehow mariadb did not like that.

I have now changed that to a backup once a day with the shutdown option.